# Is it possible to directly view the stdout and stderr of an Outlook (VSTO) add-in?

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in, outlook-addin

I have code that works perfectly fine outside of the outlook add-in context, but clearly fails when run inside an outlook add-in. I feel that if I can merely read the stderr and stdout streams I can probably figure out why it is crashing.

Before I start writing custom code to find the error, I wonder if Outlook logs these streams for add-ins somewhere already.